# A problem ocurred configuring project '@library'

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I'm getting this building error while trying to run my app with `react-native run-android`

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':@react-native-community_checkbox'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':@react-native-community_checkbox:classpath'.
   > Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-api:[1.21.1].
     Required by:
         project :@react-native-community_checkbox > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2 > io.grpc:grpc-core:1.21.1
      > Failed to list versions for io.grpc:grpc-api.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-api/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-api/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
```

My gradle configuration looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1')
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    }
}
```

My gradle version is `5.6.4`